# Visual Studio 2008 Restrict to ANSI C

Tags: c, visual-studio, c99

I want to restrict microsoft visual studio so that it can only run "C99" (ANSI C) code. Can any one give me some guideline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has not implemented c99, they have instead been putting their efforts in to standard C++.

However if all you want is to disable Microsoft's extensions to C/C++ then you can use the /Za compiler switch, but don't expect to use c99 stuff like `stdint.h`.